# Typos in Review Suspension help pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, grammar

On the help pages for review suspensions (example: [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/review-suspensions)), it says

> reviews negatively effect

but it should be "affect".

In the same paragraph:

> access to the Reviews Queue

but it should be "Review Queues".

Answer (score 15):

Fixed, thanks.

> review help pages
> is it "effect"? no! "affect!"
> copy now revised